# HTML comment is rendered as plain text on user history page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, user-history-page

*This is a bug report about a moderator-only feature.*

---

I noticed we now have a new history event type for users on the user history page.

The comment of the event action type "user with invalidated votes was deleted", is rendered as plain text instead of HTML. This breaks the link.

> [image]

Windows 10 Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit), userscripts switched off

Comment: Did you redact that link?

Comment: Yes I redacted the text in the screenshot